# What's the meaning of thread concurrency overhead time in the profiler output?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, profiling

**I'd be really appreciated if someone with good experience of Intel VTune Amplifier tell me about this thing.**

Recently I received performance analysis report from other guys who used Intel VTune Amplifier against my program. It tells, there is **high overhead time** in the thread concurrency area.

What's the meaning of the **Overhead Time**? They don't know (asked me), I don't have access to Intel VTune Amplifier.

I have vague ideas. This program has many thread sleep calls because `pthread condition` is unstable (or I did badly) in the target platform so I change many routines to do works in the loop look like below:

```
while (true)
{
   mutex.lock();
   if (event changed)
   {
      mutex.unlock();
      // do something
      break;
   }
   else
   {
      mutex.unlock();
      usleep(3 * 1000);
   }
}
```

This can be flagged as **Overhead Time**?

Any advice?

---

I found help documentation about **Overhead Time** from Intel site.
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/amplifierxe/en-us/win/ug_docs/olh/common/overhead_time.html#overhead_time

Excerpt:

> Overhead time is a duration that starts with the release of a shared resource and ends with the receipt of that resource. Ideally, the duration of Overhead time is very short because it reduces the time a thread has to wait to acquire a resource. However, not all CPU time in a parallel application may be spent on doing real pay load work. In cases when parallel runtime (Intel® Threading Building Blocks, OpenMP*) is used inefficiently, a significant portion of time may be spent inside the parallel runtime wasting CPU time at high concurrency levels. For example, this may result from low granularity of work split in recursive parallel algorithms: when the workload size becomes too low, the overhead on splitting the work and performing the housekeeping work becomes significant.

Still confusing.. Could it mean "you made unnecessary/too frequent lock"?

Comment: I do not know your exact design, but, IMHO, we may add context switching time for this overhead also.

Answer (score 2):

I am also not much of an expert on that, though I have tried to use `pthread` a bit myself.

To demonstrate my understanding of overhead time, let us take the example of a simple single-threaded program to compute an array sum:

```
for(i=0;i<NUM;i++) {
    sum += array[i];
}
```

In a simple [reasonably done] multi-threaded version of that code, the array could be broken into one piece per thread, each thread keeps its own sum, and after the threads are done, the sums are summed.

In a very poorly written multi-threaded version, the array could be broken down as before, and every thread could `atomicAdd` to a global sum.

In this case, the atomic addition can only be done by one thread at a time.  I believe that overhead time is a measure of how long all of the other threads spend while waiting to do their own `atomicAdd` (you could try writing this program to check if you want to be sure).

Of course, it also takes into account the time it takes to deal with switching the semaphores and mutexes around.  In your case, it probably means a significant amount of time is spent on the internals of the mutex.lock and mutex.unlock.

I parallelized a piece of software a while ago (using `pthread_barrier`), and had issues where it took longer to run the barriers than it did to just use one thread.  It turned out that the loop that had to have 4 barriers in it was executed quickly enough to make the overhead not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not an expert on `pthread` or Intel VTune Amplifier, but yes, locking a mutex and unlocking it will probably count as overhead time.

Locking and unlocking mutexes can be implemented as system calls, which the profiler probably would just lump under threading overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with vTune but there is an in the OS overhead switching between threads. Each time a thread stops and another loads on a processor the current thread context needs to be stored so that it can be restored when the thread next runs and then the new thread's context needs to be restored so it can carry on processing.

The problem may be that you have too many threads and so the processor is spending most of its time switching between them. Multi threaded applications will run most efficiently if there are the same number of threads as processors.